# How can I retrieve sigma-squared (point estimate of error variance) from a multiple equation GMM in STATA?

Tags: statistics

As stated in the title, I am using the -gmm- function in STATA to estimate a two-equation New Keynesian model (with appropriate instruments). I need to recover $\sigma^2$ for each equation but I have no idea how to go about this. Any help would be much appreciated!